# How to get programmable motors for an electric longboard?

Tags: motor, motor-controller

I am working on a project where I need to programmatically adjust the speed of a longboard (e.g. when the user pushes a button, the speed increases). The longboard is equipped with motors, so this would mean adjusting their torque. The way this is usually done with motors that can be bought online is by connecting an electric speed controller (ESC) or a specific variant called a Vedder ESC (VESC) to the motors. Most ESCs are not even configurable, whereas the VESC can at least be configured through certain settings. However, even the VESC does not offer direct control over the torque at all instants which is what I need.

Is there a "DIY" technique to controlling the motor torque?

Comment: Yes, control the current. You will have to adjust over time for wear, bearing changes etc.  For a better answer you need to provide more information, such as motors, batteries etc, with links pointing to technical information on all of the above. Also post a schematic, not a frizzy thing if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

Vedder's design seems ideal.
http://vedder.se/2015/01/vesc-open-source-esc/

If you control the current limit you are also controlling torque.